# pyspark Expected: decimal(16,2), Found: BINARY

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am facing the below error while trying to see data in a dataframe created from parquet files.

```
Expected: decimal(16,2), Found: BINARY
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.constructConvertNotSupportedException(VectorizedColumnReader.java:250)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBinaryBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:220)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:215)
```

I am using spark 2.4.4. I googled but didn't find enough information on this.

```
20/04/30 21:52:18 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 380, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o329.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 27, ip-10-157-181-75.extnp.national.com.au, executor 50): org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file
```

Edit: We found that it's a limitation with spark. Columns with datatype Decimal(38,2) are working fine.

Thanks,
Mc

Comment: please add code with line on which the exception is thrown

Comment: Hi I have updated my post. Is that what you requested for?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected if you are providing external schema with column datatype definition as decimal and that column contains binary value.

What you can do is read all columns as StringType and then enforce schema after seeing your dataframe.

Comment: Thank you. We have found that increasing the precision to decimal(38,2) is working as we have other columns with this datatype and we don't see any issues with it. In Spark how can we specify external schema while reading the parquet files?

Comment: You have to create the compatible Schema first using stuctType 
    schema=t.StructType([
    t.StructField('id',StringType(),True),
    t.StructField('name',StringType(),True)])  Then while reading the dataframe use df=spark.read.schema(schema).parquet(filePath)

Comment: Got it but I really don't have to do that in my case as the parquet I am reading has the same column with different datatypes. I can get going using the string field but I wanted to know if there is a way to read field with actual data type. The way other team is writing these files is like below: col1: decimal(16,2) (nullable = true) col1_std: string (nullable = true) I am thinking to use the string column and cast it while loading the target. Thank you once again for your help.